# How to force the copy of a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm using powershell to copy file to a remote computer witht he following command :

```
Copy-Item -Path [MyPath]\* -Destination \\[server]\[MyPath] -force
```

It's working great, but sometime I'm receiving the following error message: "The process cannot access the file [...] because it is being used by another process.".

Is it possible to force the file to be copy even if it's in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to get rid of the handle the process has to the file you are overwriting.

It's either a service or a desktop application accessing the file. You can find out what has access to the file using handle.exe from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals).

Once you know what is accessing the file you can stop/kill it remotely (assuming you have permissions to do so).

- [Stop a remote service](http://learn-powershell.net/2012/01/15/startingstopping-and-restarting-remote-services-with-powershell/)
- [Stop a remote process (Invoke-Command)](http://blog.wetzelerweb.com/2010/02/17/calling-stop-process-on-a-remote-machine-using-powershell/), [Stop a remote process (WMI)](http://4sysops.com/archives/query-and-kill-a-process-on-a-remote-computer-using-powershell-and-wmi/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm already closing the windows service but the file stay lock...  I will try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958123/powershell-script-to-check-application-thats-locking-a-file

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and wrote an entirely self contained script because I didn't want to depend on SysInternals. Script will identify and kill any process locking a file before making a full recursive copy.

https://github.com/Tikinsin/ForceCopy.ps1/blob/main/ForceCopy.ps1