# How to write a powershell script to release file if used by any other process

Tags: powershell, process, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am using octopus deployment with teamcity. In many cases deployment fails because "The process cannot access the file or dll because it is being used by another process. How to write a script to fix this problem. Please guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell script to check application that's locking a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958123/powershell-script-to-check-application-thats-locking-a-file)

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading into your question a little here, but it sounds to me that you're trying to deploy a website and it's failing, because the IIS worker process is using the files - what you want to do is recycle the application pool of the website before you deploy, or, if it's a high traffic website, stop the website, do the deploy, then start the website.

Answer (score 0):

Within powershell, I found a few options available.

1. `Get-Process` Can be used but it's shortcoming is that it only works with .dlls and some other code related file types.
2. Microsoft's SysInternals Suite has `handle.exe` that can be used but you need to make sure the machine has SysInternals on it.

I ran into this issue and didn't like any of the above options, so wrote an entirely self contained script because I didn't want to depend on SysInternals and needed to target more than just .dll files. This script will identify and kill any process locking a file before making a full recursive copy.

https://github.com/Tikinsin/ForceCopy.ps1/blob/main/ForceCopy.ps1