# C# - Detect locked files in a directory

Tags: c#, io

I am looking for a way to watch a directory (and its sub-directories) for locked files i.e. when an application opens a file and locks it, an event should trigger in my app.

So far I have been using FileSystemWatcher for other purposes like detecting rename, update, etc. But watching lock [using last access] requires a registry tweak as specified [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5752e234-6429-456c-bbd0-a2bbf49c5914/filesystemwatcherchanged-event-does-it-fire-when-a-file-is-accessed?forum=netfxbcl)
which is not an option so far.

Other solution that I have thought so far is continuously look for change in 'LastAccess' attribute using FileInfo object from another thread and verify if the file is locked.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I am not looking for a particular file. Here I have a directory and I need to watch for locking of file(s) in that directory.

Comment: If you wanted to do this efficiently (and reliably) you would probably need to look at implementing your own [minifilter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff540402(v=vs.85).aspx) and hooking into the appropriate API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to see if a file is locked by a process.

But you can always try yourself to access the file and fire an event based on that:

```
public bool IsFileLocked(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)){}
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        retturn true;
    }  

    return false;
}
```

This function will return true when your application could not access the file (thus it's in use by another program), false otherwise.

Comment: So your suggestion is to continuously attempt to open every file in the directory until you get an IOException? Terrible waste of resources.

Comment: Yes that's my last option.

Comment: @James I fear the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check handle.exe by Sysinternals, someone had similar question: [Check for locked files in Directory and find locking applicaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204204/check-for-locked-files-in-directory-and-find-locking-applicaiton)

I guess you might call this from your app.