# Persistent Warning: "Multiple packages failed to uninstall."

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, package-managers

I have a warning message that came to dinner but now won't leave.

> Multiple packages failed to uninstall. Restart Visual Studio to finish the process.

[image]

Unfortunately, however, restarting Visual Studio has no effect—the warning remains.

I've tried cleaning the solution as well as the project; all of my projects' assembly references are intact. I've also issued an `Update-Package -Reinstall` command—which succeeded—to no avail.

How can I set about fixing this?

Comment: Have you set your packages under the source control? If yes, please try to remove the packages from source control and instead using NuGet Package Restore. If not, please try to delete the entire ~\packages folder, then restart Visual Studio and Restore.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT — FYI I'm using the `repositoryPath` configuration, so as to centralize my packages in my dev environment (no SCC). But anyway, I believe this may have been caused by a File Explorer folder lock. I received a similar warning later, this time for a specific package; because I now knew which package it was I was able to use [Lock Hunter](https://lockhunter.com/) to discover why it wasn't deleted. I closed File Explorer, restarted VS, and the warning was no longer present. The original warning—the subject of this Q&A—was gone the next day, after having signed out and back in to Windows.

Comment: Glad to know that you have find the reason and resolved this issue.  Could you please convert your comment to answer and mark it answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT — Done. Thanks for the suggestion; I probably wouldn't have done so otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this may have been caused by a File Explorer folder lock.

I received a similar warning later, this time for a specific package; because I now knew which package it was I was able to use [Lock Hunter](https://lockhunter.com/) to discover why it wasn't deleted.

I closed File Explorer, restarted VS, and the warning was no longer present. The original warning—the subject of this Q&A—was gone the next day, after having signed out and back in to Windows.

Answer (score 7):

I tried resetting permissions on the packages folder various different ways. Reset the owner, reset all child permissions, added my user account to permissions with full control etc... Tried killing Explorer process to release locks on files.

None of that worked.

What did work was to delete the entire contents of the packages folder (made a backup first) and let Visual Studio restore all the packages the next time I loaded it.

Answer (score 4):

This was a permission issue within the packages folder for me.  Used a PS script to determine if files were locked or with other errors such as access denied; changed the permissions and restarted visual studio.  All was good afterwards.

Here is the PS script used:
[Check for locked files in Directory and find locking applicaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204204/check-for-locked-files-in-directory-and-find-locking-applicaiton)

Changed the gci command to include -Recurse.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was due to files that were under source control, were not checked out, and so could not be deleted/updated..

If you look in the Output window, and select Package Manager, then it will show you a list of the problem files that can then be manually checked out in TFS/source control.

Comment: the solution was to check those nuget's file in to TFS (even though they were marked as missing, with small yellow triangle icon) and then install the nuget.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a shared project open in multiple solutions at the same time. Closing the other Visual Studio with the shared project fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get this persistently on VS2022, and cannot find what is locking the folder contents.
However, the following one-liner on the windows command line solves it for me fairly simply:

```
for %i in (c:\mypath\myproject\packages\*.deleteme) do rmdir /q /s %~pi%~ni & del %i
```

This works by finding all the `.deleteme` files, deleting the matching folder, then deleting the `.deleteme` file itself.  This doesn't seem to have any problems with permissions or locking, even on a non-administrator command line.

To see what this is going to do first:

```
for %i in (c:\mypath\myproject\packages\*.deleteme) do @echo rmdir /q /s %~pi%~ni & @echo del %i
```

Resulting in, for example:

```
rmdir /q /s \mypath\myproject\packages\JsonSubTypes.2.0.1
del c:\mypath\myproject\packages\JsonSubTypes.2.0.1.deleteme
rmdir /q /s \mypath\myproject\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.6.0.0
del c:\mypath\myproject\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.6.0.0.deleteme
```

One easy reusable solution is to build this into a batch file which takes a parameter, remembering to double up the `%` signs:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (%%1\*.deleteme) do echo rmdir /q /s %%~pi%%~ni & echo del %%i
```

Save that in your solution folder, then just drag-drop the packages folder onto it.

This would also be easy to automate with something like the [Command Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandTaskRunner) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you don't have dotPeek open, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the **VBScriptCompiler.exe** was still running behind the scenes even after Visual Studio was closed. Once I ended that task in Task Manager, I was able to delete the "packages" folder and let nuget restore everything.