# Get Build Date in .NET MAUI csproj

Tags: c#, maui

I tried to get build date in the csproj of a .NET MAUI solution file like I did in a regular WPF Application:
1.0 $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString())

But I cant compile it , I get an error NETSDK1005 ... project.assets.json
I tried it with the current VS2022 17.4.3 and also Preview 17.5.0 2.0

If it don't work with ApplicationDisplayVersion is there any other way to get the build date at runtime ?

Comment: For Win, Custom AssemblyAttribute is working. Your csproj can do all the work. PropertyGRoup <BuildDate>, and ItemGroup <AssemblyAttribute> referencing sealed class with one string parameter. For Android and IOS this will not work. You should google the same question, but change MAUI with Xamarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MSBuild property. Besides having only the assembly version we can have the version + time of the build. We could use SourceRevisionId tag to tell .NET compiler do this.

Add these following to yourappname.csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <SourceRevisionId>build$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))</SourceRevisionId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you could retrieve the build date through *AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute* using the following code:

```
private static DateTime GetBuildDate(Assembly assembly)
{
    const string BuildVersionMetadataPrefix = "+build";

    var attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>();
    if (attribute?.InformationalVersion != null)
    {
        var value = attribute.InformationalVersion;
        var index = value.IndexOf(BuildVersionMetadataPrefix);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            value = value.Substring(index + BuildVersionMetadataPrefix.Length);
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return default;
}
```

Then you could get build date through the method

```
DateTime dt = GetBuildDate(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

For more info, you could refer to [Getting the date of build of a .NET assembly at runtime](https://www.meziantou.net/getting-the-date-of-build-of-a-dotnet-assembly-at-runtime.htm#method-2-assemblyinf).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Great thats it. Thanks Liqun

Comment: do you think this is better than this other approach?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786536/visual-studio-2019-restore-completed-nuget-loop

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The link you post is about solving a restoring package issue while this post is getting Build Date in .NET MAUI csproj.