# The package at 'Path' failed to uninstall

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, uninstallation

So I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11.  I am trying to install a nuget package.

I get the message The package at 'Path' failed to uninstall.

So I restart and guess what - it makes no difference.  Its not a re-install so the package isnt already there.  It does create the folder and contents in the packages folder.  I have closed VS and manually deleted it.  The same package works fine in another project!

Anybody any ideas how I move this forward?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answers for this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/43421825/3814721 might help you.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you can try the following methods.

1. Go to Tools>Options>NuGet Package Manager>General and Clear All NuGet Cache(s).
   [image]
2. [Restore package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore).
3. [Reinstall package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages).
4. Check your package.config file for package dependencies.

Comment: Thank you.  That one has sorted it for me