# fuser equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, directory, file-handling, fuser

I want to delete a directory, but a process is using it.

```
 mv : Access to the path 'C:\Users\mike\Documents\myapp\node_modules\' is denied.
```

Explorer mentions the dir is in use. Is there a Windows Powershell equivalent of `fuser`?

Note this is a powershell question. I don't want to launch a GUI app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$lockedFolder="C:\Windows\System32"
Get-Process | %{$processVar = $_;$_.Modules | %{if($_.FileName -like "$lockedFolder*"){$processVar.Name + " PID:" + $processVar.id}}}
```

This looks for every process that's running in the folder. (or in subdirectories)

With this script, you'll get some more informations:

```
$lockedFolder="C:\Windows\System32" 
Get-Process | %{$processVar = $_;$_.Modules | %{if($_.FileName -like "$lockedFolder*"){$processVar.Name + " PID:" + $processVar.id + " FullName: " + $_.FileName }}}
```

I think there is no equivalent to fuser, but there is a tool called handle.exe that has to be installed first.

[PowerShell script to check an application that's locking a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958123/powershell-script-to-check-an-application-thats-locking-a-file)

Comment: Thanks @Eldo.Ob! I notice this only seems to work with a full path - any way to make it work with a relative folder name?

Comment: You're welcome :) 
No it's not a full path. The script gets all processes, that is running in the given directory or subdirectories. So if you set "D:\" into the var $lockedFolder, you'll get all processes running in Directory D:\ or subdirectories. Just try: 
`$lockedFolder="C:\Windows\System32"
Get-Process | %{$processVar = $_;$_.Modules | %{if($_.FileName -like "$lockedFolder*"){$processVar.Name + " PID:" + $processVar.id + " FullName: " + $processVar.FileName }}}`

Comment: oh I made a mistake: `$lockedFolder="C:\Windows\System32" Get-Process | %{$processVar = $_;$_.Modules | %{if($_.FileName -like "$lockedFolder*"){$processVar.Name + " PID:" + $processVar.id + " FullName: " + $_.FileName }}}`

Comment: I mean you have to set $lockedFolder to a full path, not a relative one - I'd like to make this into a short function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of @Eldo.Ob's excellent answer that handles relative files.

```
function fuser($relativeFile){
  $file = Resolve-Path $relativeFile
  foreach ( $Process in (Get-Process)) {
    foreach ( $Module in $Process.Modules) {
      if ( $Module.FileName -like "$file*" ) {
        $Process | select id, path
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In use:

```
> fuser .\node_modules\

  Id Path
  -- ----
2660 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```