# Invoke-Command does not kill process on remote machine

Tags: powershell

Before deployment, I'm trying to kill processes that lock files using PowerShell Invoke-Command

This is my code:

```bsh
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("Admin",$password)

$scriptBlock = {Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like 'MyApp*'} | Stop-Process}

Invoke-Command -computername Agent1 -Credential $credentials -scriptblock $scriptBlock
```

Unfortunately it does not do anything and no errors are thrown.

On the machine, this works fine:

```bsh
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like 'MyApp*'} | Stop-Process
```

Comment: if there's a process running in the background then it's not going to have a Window Title.  Try `Enter-PSSession -computername Agent1` and then do a `Get-Process -IncludeUsername | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle }`  You should get an empty result, even if you login to Agent1 via RDP and launch notepad or something you'll still get no result if you try to list that through a remote session.

Comment: The process i'm trying to kill is running as a console app and has title matching the one in my stop-process script. With the exact same command, on the Agent1 machine, I'm able to kill it, running:
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like 'MyApp*'} | Stop-Process


I've tried Enter-PSSession -computername Agent1 -credential $credentials 
It worked fine, but then, same. Running command has no result.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it works using `Enter-PSSession`, yes?  Try creating a session object using `New-PSSession`, and then passing that object to `Enter-PSSession` and testing; if that works then try passing the session object to `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: I'm able to connect to the machine, but when I try to actually stop any process there, it doesn't..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described above create a PS session object:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("Admin",$password)

$scriptBlock = {
    $process = Get-Process
    $process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like 'MyApp*'} | Stop-Process}
    $process
}
$session = New-PsSession -ComputerName "Agent1" -Credentials $credentials

$remoteProcess = Invoke-Command -Session $session -Credential $credentials -scriptblock $scriptBlock

$remoteProcess | format-table
```

Above code will also return you a list processes running on the remote host. Based on `$remoteProcess` you'll see if the process to kill was running or not. I also set the `ErrorActionPreference` to `stop` which forces above code to stop on the first error (in case of the session could not be created).

Hope that helps

Comment: $session = New-PsSession -ComputerName "Agent1" -Credentials $credentials -should be  -Credential $credentials (little typo there, extra 's')

However, after this:
$remoteProcess = Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock $scriptBlock

$remoteProcess | format-table - this executes but no result, process is still running

Comment: I think this here might be what you need to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958123/powershell-script-to-check-an-application-thats-locking-a-file

Comment: Using ```Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like 'MyApp*'``` does not work, apparently because of luck of the access to UI. However ```Stop-Process -Name "cmd*" -Force``` does the work in my case, even it is not what I was looking for. 
Thanks for help guys!