# Powershell script to to delete a directory which contains jar that is used by other process

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete a folder with all the subfolder and contains. But there are jar files used by another process. So it fails. I tried:-

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath "C:\tools\wlp-8.5.5.9\usr\servers\dev\workarea" -Force -Recurse
```

But it fails:-

Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\tools\wlp-8.5.5.9\usr\servers\dev\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\142\0.cp\lib\cxf-core-3.0.3.jar: The process cannot access the file 'cxf-core-3.0.3.jar' because it is being used by another process.

How can I forcefully delete this folder by PowerShell script?

Comment: Your only option is to identify the specific processes that are using the `.jar` files and _kill_ (forcefully terminate) them with, e.g., `Stop-Process`.

Comment: I'm not sure which process to kill.

Comment: Well, `java` processes would be the obvious candidates, but if that is too broad, more work is needed - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/958123/45375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly getting the files which are opened by java then kill the required process :

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'Java.exe'") | Select-Object handle, CommandLine
```

then stop it:

```
Stop-Process -Id XXXXX -force -whatif 
# remove -whatif , if you want to execute the command
```

Comment: handle CommandLine
------ -----------

10368  "C:\tools\java\jre\bin\java"  "-javaagent:C:\tools\wlp-8.5.5.9\bin\tools\ws-javaagent.jar" -Djava.awt.headl...   
So how do I kill this process by force?

Comment: Stop-Process -Id handle -force -whatif Got errro:- Stop-Process : Cannot bind parameter 'Id'. Cannot convert value "handle" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.". I have to convert the handle .
Later tried Stop-Process -Id 10368  -force -whatif. Output:- What if: Performing the operation "Stop-Process" on target "java (10368)".
But after that I tried again (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'Java.exe'") | Select-Object handle, CommandLine. It was showing the same output of the Get-WmiObject. Meaing it was not stop

Comment: Handle= your process id ~ 10368

Comment: To make a script, I have to convert  Handle to int. How to do it?  Also even if I tried   Stop-Process -Id 10368  -force -whatif . It doesn't stop the process. Coz I get same output when tried (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'Java.exe'") | Select-Object handle, CommandLine

handle CommandLine
------ -----------
10368  "C:\tools\java\jre\bin\java"  "-javaagent:C:\tools\wlp-8.5.5.9\bin\tools\ws-javaagent.jar" -Djava.awt.headl...