# How to kill all process that run under a folder?

Tags: powershell, cmd, process, kill

I want to replace some files in folder, and I see that there are multiple process under the folder that prevent me from doing that.

How can I kill all process process that run under a folder?

Comment: Use handle.exe from Sysinternal and wrap it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958123/powershell-script-to-check-an-application-thats-locking-a-file

Comment: or if you are prefer `cmd`, use `wmic process`

Comment: The supported Windows way is to rename the open files (open executable files can be renamed), copy your new files in, and either restart the app or restart the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using powershell:

1. Navigate the current powershell directory to the destination path by:

`cd "%*DestinationPath*%"`

2. `Get-Process | ?{$_.path -and (test-path (split-path $_.path -leaf ))} | Stop-Process -Force`

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) (because [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) is one of your tags), use `wmic process`:

```
@echo off
set "dir=YOUR PATH HERE"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic process get executablepath') do (
    for /f "eol= tokens=*" %%A in ("%%a") do (
        echo(%%~dpA | findstr /I %dir% >nul 2>&1
        if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 taskkill /F /IM "%%~nxA"
    )
)
```

---

Note: This is **NOT** foolproof, all processes with the same name will get killed